Cannot activate google admin account when failing to validate phone number
I am stuck in the following loop: We are trying to migrate a domain we own and is currently registered with Godaddy with some basic site into google workspace. but I can't pass the phone number validation step and I can't get any usefull support without it.
The place where we get stack is the following: we create an admin account using the google workspace "sign up" option. the account name is <private name>-admin@<my domain>
before we can do anything we need to sign in to the admin console, so the flow is:

browse to "admin.google.com" -> getting a prompt that we need to use the admin account (see image)
clicking on "add account" (basically the only option in this page) -> taking me to "validate your identity" page (see image)
in the validation page I type the company owner phone number -> I get a an error that this number cannot be used. when I try multiple time I get a message the this number was used too many times

This is basically it - we are stuck in this loop, cannot log in to the admin console, and all the support pages either give useless advice or asks as to login for some paid/pro support.
So far, nothing has worked. I would be happy if there is a way to get a known solution or reach usefull technical support.
getting to admin.google.com validate your identity page
Other things we tried:

using my personal phone number -> same errors
using the owner other phone number -> same errors
using the voice call instead of text message -> same error message
waiting for 2 weeks, hoping that some rate limiting expire -> same errors




It's impossible for us to help you with the signup workflow; only Google can. Contact them via their support pages.

@vidarlo - thanks, these options only lead to sales support or sending you to read more forms. to get technical support I was required to purchase it, which (again) is not possible if you can't login to the admin account.

Still nothing we're able to do...

I ended up contacting google workspace support.
Using the "Sign in issues" form I was eventually contacted over the phone.
Per the (very helpfull) support person request, I sent him the phone number I used for validation and also was requested to add a specific CNAME entry to my web site dns records.
After doing so he escalated the issue which led to it being solved after apx 24 hours
This is the form I used to get help
(https://support.google.com/a/contact/recovery_form)
After I managed to log in to the admin console, I can see that the account was initially suspended, which probably caused validation to fail.
Why it was suspended on the first place, I would probably never know.
And I do hope that someone at google workspace would figure how useless is the error messages you get saying that "you can't use this number" when actually the account is suspended and no number will ever solve your problem.
so at least I hope someone learn from my experience, should they face a similar problem.
